# Finding multiple substrings in a single string using Perl

Tags: perl, substring

I need to take the following string and break it into chunks:

> [ToNode=cup-subscriber][Reason=Critical service is
>   down][FromNode=cup-publisher][AppID=Cisco UP Server Recovery Manager]

Each chunk is encapsulated in brackets.  I'm looking to do this in Perl, and am looking for direction on a method.

Thanks!

Comment: `@chunks = split /(?:\]|^)(?:\[|$)/, $string` for a rather quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split at the point between `]` and a `[` using lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
$str = '[ToNode=cup-subscriber][Reason=Critical service is down]
        [FromNode=cup-publisher][AppID=Cisco UP Server Recovery Manager]';

@pieces = split/(?<=\])(?=\[)/,$str;
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/DC84u)

Comment: This is the one I used.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Use the /g modifier for regular expressions. Either in list context to extract into an array:

```
$data = "[ToNode=cup-subscriber][Reason=Critical service is down][FromNode=cup-publisher][AppID=Cisco UP Server Recovery Manager]"
my @chunk = ( $data =~ /\[(.*?)\]/g );
```

or in a while loop to iterate over the chunks:

```
$data = "[ToNode=cup-subscriber][Reason=Critical service is down][FromNode=cup-publisher][AppID=Cisco UP Server Recovery Manager]"
while ( $data =~ /\[(.*?)\]/g ) {
    process($1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my $str = '[ToNode=cup-subscriber][Reason=Critical service is down][FromNode=cup-publisher][AppID=Cisco UP Server Recovery Manager]';
my %fields = $str =~ m{\[([^][=]+)=([^][=]+)\]}g;
say "$_: $fields{$_}" for sort keys %fields;
```

Or more verbosely:

```
my $str = '[ToNode=cup-subscriber][Reason=Critical service is down][FromNode=cup-publisher][AppID=Cisco UP Server Recovery Manager]';

# Capture all occurrences of ...
my %fields = $str =~ m{
            \[              # Open bracket
            ( [^][=]+ )     # Sequence of 1 or more non ][= characters
            =               # Equals
            ( [^][=]+ )     # Sequence of 1 or more non ][= characters
            \]              # Close bracket
        }xg;

# Dump contents of %fields
say "$_: $fields{$_}" for sort keys %fields;
```